# Definition of 'bent' used in D&D lore

Tags: dnd-5e, terminology, half-elf

What is the meaning of *bent* in this sentence (from the *Dungeons & Dragons Player's Handbook* 5th edition)?

> Half-elves share the chaotic **bent** of their elven heritage.

I have tried looking this definition up to match this context, but I could not find one.  Does anyone have a reliable source that would define it as it is used above?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's a non-RPG vocabulary question.

Answer (score 8):

Webster defined *bent* as follows:

> BENT, participle passive Strained; incurvated; made crooked; **inclined**; subdued.

(http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/bent).

In this sentence, the word "bent" is used to show that half-elves are inclined to chaotic alignments. In other words, their alignment bends toward chaos rather than law.

Comment: Nice.  I am having a hard time getting away from the OED.  They were once great and proud.  Now they add several words a year like twerk and manspacing

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I think you misunderstand the OED; it was the first dictionary to be established with the specific aim of mapping language as it is, not as the compilers would like it to be. You can't blame the mapmaker for showing a swamp where there is a swamp just because you prefer mountains.

Comment: I have thought more about this definition source above.  I am not convinced it serves as a authority to back the context used in the sentence cited from the Handbook.  The word defined in Webster's is an adjective.  The sentence in the OP uses this word as a noun.  I am now not sure this satisfies my question.  I would unmark this as the answer, but moderation has seen fit to quibble about the validity of this question.  I would like to continue this, and see if I can get a better understanding of this context.

Comment: This answer will work, along with +[Oblivious Sage] and his clarification.

Answer (score 6):

Bent used in this case refers to a tendency, a leaning towards.

Half-elves share the chaotic tendencies of their elven heritage.

Comment: +1 because it addresses the term being used as a noun, which is the usage in the book under discussion.